# Steps to setup the bluetooth communication of rasp pi 3 with hm-10 wired on tm4c microcontroller

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I would be happy if anyone could give me a hint, because surprisingly I couldn't find any source where the Pi setup for hm-10 is explained, my question is how to setup the Rasp Pi 3 to connect to hm-10 over bluetooth and send the commands?

My current setup as follows, hm-10 is installed on breadboard and the pin connections are going to tm4c microcontroller, now I am trying to communicate rasp pi 3 with hm-10 over bluetooth in order to send the commands to hm-10 from rasp pi.

Please help, because I am really stuck on this issue for several days.